# Generate object from Typescript interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I realize this is essentially the opposite intent of Typescript, but I would like to be able to programmatically generate an object FROM a typescript interface. Basically, I want something like this:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string
}

const generateObjFromInterface = (Foo) => // { bar: 'string'}
```

I -do not- mind how contrived the implementation is if it IS possible! If it is categorically impossible that would also be helpful information!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only way is to process the source code since interfaces don't exist at runtime. Something similar to what [this library](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. As typescript 2.4 is around the corner we can use custom transformers for typescript during compilation and get the list of all properties that are there and as a result create object with such properties.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys), but please note - as I have said this require to use typescript 2.4+ that is not yet in stable release

Comment: This looks literally like my dream solution, thanks so much!

Comment: have you successfully used this package at all? I've been struggling to determine if this is user error or a problem with the package itself but I keep getting the following error: ts_transformer_keys_1.keys is not a function

Comment: No I have not used it in practice. Have you followed the guide on how to compile the program: https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys#how-to-use-the-custom-transformer? This is important step.

Answer (score 2):

Since TypeScript's interfaces are not present in the JavaScript output, runtime reflection over an interface is impossible.

Given this TypeScript:

```
interface Foo {
    bar: string
}
```

This is the resultant JavaScript:

[image]

Since there is no JavaScript, what you want to do <s>is categorically impossible</s> is very contrived.

Edit: Come to think of it, you *could* find, read, and parse the *.ts source file at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I did it by using [intermock](https://github.com/google/intermock) (Google)
[Here is](https://google.github.io/intermock/) a demo page

Answer (score 0):

I also was searching for something that could do it and I didn't find anything. So I build this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-validator-mocker, which can generate random data for classes attributes annotated with class-validator's decorators. Worked pretty well for my purposes.